# ChartJS: Remove padding to the right of chart caused by tick labels

Tags: chart.js

I'm using the latest version of Chart.js and am trying to make the line chart fit run right up to the edge of the containing div but when I enable the yAxes ticks it adds a small padding to the right or in other words pushes the graph to the left.

How can I have tick labels and also have the chart extend to the edges of the `<canvas />`?

See screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be able to resolve some things like that by using the [different callback hooks](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/#callbacks) that are available in the update process.

Testing things out on my own, I was able get it to fix that gap by setting the right padding on the axis to `0` in the `afterFit` method, which based on the docs is:

> Callback that runs after the scale fits to the canvas

```js
const options = {
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      afterFit: (axis) => {
        axis.paddingRight = 0;
      }
    }]
  }
}
```